# Cannot read property 'state' of undefined

Tags: lightning-aura-components, button-overrides

I am new at coding and receiving an error "Action failed: c:NewMarketingTicket$controller$init [Cannot read property 'state' of undefined]" when accessing a custom LC button override when creating a new record.  Can I please have some help resolving this error?  Thank you in advance!

Edit: Controller below fixed above error, but produces new error: Action failed: c:NewMarketingTicket$controller$init [action is not defined]

Component

```
    <aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens, lightning:actionOverride, force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader, force:hasRecordId" access="global" >

    <aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
    <aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
    <lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" />

</aura:component>
```

Controller

```
({
init : function (component) {
    // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = pageRef.getState; 
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log("From server: "
                        + response.getReturnValue()
                        + '\n' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert("Continuation action is INCOMPLETE");
        }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef;
        
        if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
            base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
        }
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));
        
    });
    //Pass input IDs
    var inputVariables = [
        {
            name : 'recordId',
            type : 'String',
            value : '{!v.recordId}'
        },
        {
            name : 'TicketsInfoId',
            type : 'String',
            value : '{!v.recordId.Ticket_Number__c.Id}'
        }
    ];
    
    
    //Run flow
    flow.startFlow("Marketing_Ticket_Tracker_New_Record", inputVariables);
}})
```

**Edit:  New code**

Cmp

```
<aura:component implements="lightning:availableForFlowScreens,lightning:actionOverride,force:lightningQuickActionWithoutHeader,force:hasRecordId" access="global" controller="MarketingTickets">

<aura:handler name="init" value="{!this}" action="{!c.init}" />
<aura:attribute name="recordId" type="Id" />
<lightning:flow aura:id="flowData" /> </aura:component>
```

JS controller

```
({
init : function (component) {
    // Find the component whose aura:id is "flowData"
    var flow = component.find("flowData");
    var pageRef = component.get("v.pageReference");
    
    var action = component.get("c.getVenueAttendees");
    action.setParams({ paramName : component.get("v.recordId") });
    
    action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
        var state = pageRef.getState; 
        if (state === "SUCCESS") {
            console.log("From server: "
                        + response.getReturnValue()
                        + '\n' + JSON.stringify(response.getReturnValue()));
        }
        else if (state === "INCOMPLETE") {
            alert("Continuation action is INCOMPLETE");
        }
            else if (state === "ERROR") {
                var errors = response.getError();
                if (errors) {
                    if (errors[0] && errors[0].message) {
                        console.log("Error message: " +
                                    errors[0].message);
                    }
                } else {
                    console.log("Unknown error");
                }
            }
        var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef;
        
        if (base64Context.startsWith("1\.")) {
            base64Context = base64Context.substring(2);
        }
        var addressableContext = JSON.parse(window.atob(base64Context));
        
    });
    //Pass input IDs
    var inputVariables = [
        {
            name : 'recordId',
            type : 'String',
            value : '{!v.recordId}'
        },
        {
            name : 'TicketsInfoId',
            type : 'String',
            value : '{!v.recordId.Ticket_Number__c.Id}'
        }
    ];
    
    
    //Run flow
    flow.startFlow("Marketing_Ticket_Tracker_New_Record", inputVariables);
}})
```

Apex Controller

```
public with sharing class MarketingTickets {

@AuraEnabled(cacheable=true)
public static List<Venue_Attendee__c> getVenueAttendees(String VenueTicketId) {
    return [SELECT Ticket_Number__r.Id, Id 
            FROM Venue_Attendee__c
            WHERE Ticket_Number__r.Id = :VenueTicketId LIMIT 1];
}}
```

Comment: `var base64Context = state.inContextOfRef` here you try to read a property of `state` variable which is `undefined`

Comment: @OlehBerehovskyi I see, how would I define that variable?

Comment: Updated controller resolved previous error, but produces error - Action failed: c:NewMarketingTicket$controller$init [action is not defined]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Buddy, for your action error, just include this before:

> ```
>     var action = cmp.get("c.myApexMethodName");
>     action.setParams({ paramName : cmp.get("v.ParamValue") });
>
>     // Create a callback that is executed after 
>     // the server-side action returns
>     action.setCallback(this, function(response) {
>       //logic
>     }
> ```

Also do not forget to icnlude the controller reference in your aura:component tag

```
<aura:component controller="MyApexcontroller">
```

Refer to this link: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/controllers_server_actions_call.htm

Comment: Thank you for that!! I have completed the apex controller and there are no errors in code, however I get one when trying to create a new record (this is replacing the standard button).  Does my code look good? If it does, I know the error is somewhere in the screen flow.

Comment: {!v.recordId} and {!v.recordId.Ticket_Number__c.Id} dont really exists, you should use response.getReturnValue().Id and response.getReturnValue().Ticket_Number__r.Id instead. Can you try?

Comment: This time I get error: An unhandled fault has occurred in this flow
An unhandled fault has occurred while processing the flow. Please contact your system administrator for more information.    But this is different than the last, before it was a SFDC error code

Comment: found this after running debug log:  FLOW_ELEMENT_ERROR|This error occurred when the flow tried to look up records: 
FROM Venue_Attendee__c WHERE ((Id = 'response.getReturnValue().Id')) and ERROR at Row:1:Column:60
invalid ID field: response.getReturnValue().Id

Comment: you should not use quotes, just: value : response.getReturnValue().Id. Or maybe id, with lowercase, since javaascript is case sensitive. Anyway I recomend you to learn to use chrome development tools for debugging, they are great and so helpful

Comment: I removed quotes and system is now saying Response is not defined, but isn't this a system tag?  I really appreciate all of your help on this..

Comment: Right. Please, move the //Pass input Ids and /Run flow into the callback when the response is success. there response will be defined Right after your console.log(JSON.stringify...)

Comment: Thank you!  No errors are being produced, but the screen doesn't load anything when I click 'New' to load the screen flow.  Am I only missing a design for the screen in dev console?

Comment: I am sorry I am afraid I cannot really help you with the provided info and details. You can consider closig this post if your initial question was answered and maybe provide the details of the flow in other post. We can connect in linkedin or somehow else and I will try to find a time to help since it seems you need it :)